# Draggable Item Expansion For Flutter, Like Magnifiy Glass or Video Progress Bar Preview

Tags: flutter, user-interface, widget, gesturedetector

I would like to implement a user interface using Flutter, but am unsure which widget would be the best (closest) functionality to what I need. It maybe the exact widget I need already exists and I'm un able to find it. Thinking I might need to use the GestureDetector's onLongPressMoveUpdate, but this seems a bit primitive if I could reuse some sort of video preview widget that might save some time.

**Pattern**:
I have a large number of items that have a natural sequence, such that a user would know the approximate posit of any item in the sequence. I would like a UI element that would allow the user to use their knowledge of the sequence to start their search for an item where they guess the it to be, then adjust back and forth in the sequence depending on how the select item looks compared to what they are looking for.

**Similar example**:
Draggable preview box used to seek on the progress bar of a video in youtube.

**Constraints**:

- User will not have keyboard so text search would need to pop up an on-screen keyboard (not desirable)
- Using Flutter

Comment: how would you show "the select item compared to what they are looking for."? in other words, how would you like to differentiate those items?

Comment: @pskink the user would differentiate, eyeball the detail.
LongPress on a point on the element representing the sequence, then drag left and right to find the right item, release to finalize selection.  Details of the items adjacent may help the selection.

Comment: so the problem is not how to show the difference but rather the whole  gesture handling? if so, I think that single `GestureDetector` would handle that all gesture interaction, did you try that?

Comment: @pskink I was just wanted to see the whole thing had been baked as a navigation element already by someone, with all the nice scaling to slide the item pagination at a comfortable rate, etc. Being Lazy basically. :)